# Seg faults on c dataypes in python using ctypes

Tags: python, ctypes

Am very new to `ctypes`. Trying to use ctypes as I want to play with the libquicktime library to insert text tracks to a movie using python. I'm trying the following and I get seg faults.
I think as [the doc](http://libquicktime.sourceforge.net/doc/apiref/group__text__encode.html#gad399707ef885b3643f9bbee2890f0946) says I should be passing `ins64_t` duration, (in my case random number 123 for tests). Wonder how do I define `int64_t` var:

```
>> import ctypes    
>> lqt = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary('libquicktime.so.0')    
>> qth = lqt.quicktime_open('/home/blah/movies/Test.018699.mov', 0, 1)    
>> lqt.lqt_add_text_track(qth)    
0    
>> lqt.lqt_set_text_language(qth, 1, 'eng')    
0    
>> lqt.lqt_write_text(qth, 1, 'test message', 123)
Segmentation fault
```

Would be very helpful if someone could explain how do I map such datatypes like (int64, uint64) in python ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define the argument types to the function before calling it.

```
lqt.lqt_write_text.argtypes = [ctypes.c_void_p,ctypes.c_int,ctypes.c_char_p,ctypes.c_int64]
lqt.lqt_write_text.restype = None
lqt.lqt_write_text(qth, 1, 'test message', 123)
```

Note opaque types like `quicktime_t` can just substitute a void pointer as the type.

Comment: You're welcome.  If the answer helped you, you can up vote and select an answer as acceptable by clicking the checkmark to the left of it.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [function prototypes](http://docs.python.org/library/ctypes.html#specifying-the-required-argument-types-function-prototypes) to check arguments.

`int64_t` is  `ctypes.c_int64`.

Comment: Tried that too. Seg Faults.

>> lqt.lqt_write_text(qth, 1, 'test message', ctypes.c_int64(1))

Segmentation fault